# HTML tag for text on single row <i> vs <p> vs <div>

Tags: html, css

I have two text fields which I want to show side by side

```
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" [routerLink]="['/']" href="#page-top">
      <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-2x " aria-hidden="true"></i> 
      <h4 class="title">My Poems </h4>
    </a>
  </div>
```

If I use `<i>` for the `<h4>`, they remain side by side. Any other tag I use `(<div>, <p>, <span>)` all puts in the next row.

I have changed the css width of the navbar-brand, navbar-header so it doesn't wrap around. Am I missing something... do I need to give float or some other way to make it stand side by side

Comment: `<h4>`, `<div>`, and `<p>` are all block level elements. `<span>` however is inline and shouldn't push anything. Post a [mcve] including the relevant CSS so we can see the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add display:inline or display:inline-block to your h4 tag like this

```
<h4 class="title" style="display:inline-block">My Poems </h4>
```

or give your element a classname and add define its style to display inline-block like this

```
<h4 class="title myTitle">My Poems </h4>

.myTitle{display:inline-block;}
```